# Class Schedule difficulty

Tags: html, html-table

I am having a bit of trouble making a class schedule in HTML coding, I got to have the times like: 1:00, 1:30 etc. on the left and in the main body having rowspans for the different classes on the different days.

An example would be I have the same classes on monday and wednesday but no classes on tuesday thursday friday saturday or sunday.

In my efforts so far I am able to span the rows but unfortunately get extra columns at the end.

```
  <table border="1">
<tr>
<th>TIME</th>
<th>Monday</th>
<th>Tuesday</th>
<th>Wednesday</th>
<th>Thursday</th>
<th>Friday</th>
<th>Saturday</th>
<th>Sunday</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>8:00AM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>8:30AM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>9:00AM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>9:30AM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>10:00AM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>10:30</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>11:00AM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>11:30AM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>12:00PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>12:30PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>1:00PM</th>
<td rowspan="6">FA 3550 - 001</td>
<td></td>
<td rowspan="6">FA 3550 - 001</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>1:30PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>2:00PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>2:30PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>3:00PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>4:00PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>5:00PM</th>
<td rowspan="3">class</td>
<td></td>
<td rowspan ="3">class</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>5:30PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>6:00PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>6:30PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td rowspan="5">class</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>7:00PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>7:30PM</th>
<td rowspan="6">class</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>8:00PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>8:30PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>9:00PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>9:30PM</th>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show us your existing HTML code so we know what you've tried and where exactly things are going wrong. Use a site like [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.ne) to replicate the issue and post the relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: I posted the code, but unfortunately the link provided doesn't work

Comment: Basically speaking, when you use the `colspan` or `rowspan` attributes, 2 things happen. **1** The cell is extended right or down **2** the number of cells required in the horizontal or vertical directions is reduced. Try this: remove 2 pairs of `<td></td>` from the rows labelled '1.30', '2:00', '2:30', '3:00' & '4:00' - you should now see the extra cells between 1:30 and 4:00 disappear. You have 2 cells with rowspan=6 to the left of these cells, so don't need to include them in the mark-up any-more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of your problem.. notice how in one of the rows, I filled in the letter "d" for each cell for that row:

http://jsfiddle.net/57FLP/

```
<tr>
    <th>1:00PM</th>
    <td rowspan="6">FA 3550 - 001</td>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="6">FA 3550 - 001</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>1:30PM</th>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>d</td>
</tr>
```

Looking at the html code, the letter 'd' for each `<td></td>`, which happens to be 7 times; your table also shows it 7 times; however because you are doing a rowspan, from one of your rows somewhere in the middle, you're cutting into the rows below it. Don't think of your row span as a knife cutting through butter, think of it as your hand chopping down on a bunch of apples (not cutting through them, but moving them, the apple will then fill up the sides as it has no where else to go); this is analogous as to what is happening with you table.

Just think about what happens if all your `<td></td>` are filled with data, and you just happen to convert one as a rowspan, where would all that data go? You don't want to lose any of it.

What you need to do, is for every change you make, you have to cut off the remaining unused tds from your table.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/57FLP/1/ has some cleanup, removing extra `<td>` pairs for rows that have a `rowspan` coming in from above.